# Where is MySQL's the POINT() function documented?

Tags: mysql, geospatial, wkt

It seems like besides using WKT and the GeomFromText function, MySQL support an other method of creating geometries. The function `POINT()` is used in the examples in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/geometry-property-functions.html#point-property-functions), but I can not find where the function itself is documented.

This one is pretty straightforward, but I wonder if there are any other functions which can be used as well, instead of parsing WKT strings.

Comment: `POINT` is a *type* not a function. It encapsulates an x and y value pair.

Comment: @BrianRoach In the examples it is called as a function. Can every *type* be used like that?

Comment: Sorry, I get the disconnect now - posted a full answer that I hope answers the question and links to the appropriate docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL has a spacial data type `POINT`. It's a type that encapsulates an x and y value pair to represent a coordinate in some space.

You can create a table with a column of that type via:

> CREATE TABLE my_table (pt POINT);

For every spacial type there's a "constructor" function(s) to create a value of that type. For example, `Point(x,y)` - it returns a value of type `POINT` to be stored in the db, used in another function, etc:

> INSERT INTO my_table (pt) VALUES (Point(1,2));

The docs that cover the functions for creating values of these types (incl. the `Point()` function) can be found at [Creating spacial values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-spatial-values.html#gis-mysql-specific-functions) and the section of the manual that it's in covers spacial types in general.

Comment: Thanks. These were the function I was looking for. Please add #gis-mysql-specific-functions to the link for easier reference.

Comment: Is it true that POINT() can not be used in views?

Answer (score 4):

`POINT` is not a function, it's a data type.

You use it like `POINT(100, 20)` to give you a coordinate of `x = 100, y = 20`.

It is documented at [12.16.2.3 Class Point](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-point.html):

> A `Point` is a geometry that represents a single location in coordinate space.

> **`Point` Examples**
>
> Imagine a large-scale map of the world with many cities. A `Point` object could represent each city.
>
> On a city map, a `Point` object could represent a bus stop.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I still can't see the parameters for the 'constructor'. Can `LineString()` be called as a function as well? In that case how the parameters should look like?

Comment: @vbence There are only 2 parameters - `x, y`

Comment: `Point()` is the obvious one to figure out. In the meantime I learned that `LineString(Point(), Point())` is also valid. But: I'm still looking for a documentation about these *constructor(?)* functions.

Answer (score 2):

This is where MySQL documents [Point](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-class-point.html) class.

> A Point is a geometry that represents a single location in coordinate space.

Answer (score 1):

It is documented here under title **[12.16.5 MySQL-Specific Functions That Create Geometry Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html)**

If you need to understand this constructor function and other information on Spatial Type in MySQL, follow my article on Medium **[Playing with Geometry/Spatial Data Types in MySQL](https://itnext.io/playing-with-geometry-spatial-data-type-in-mysql-645b83880331)**